# Blender Became Slow

Tags: python

I used Blender 2.79B for a while … but after I installed windows blender became very slow … i have a Toshiba laptop with Pentium and 4 giga ram and it was fine before windows installation … I try to download intel update and windows but nothing

Comment: In my opinion this has nothing to do with Blender.

Comment: Reboot, reinstall graphics drivers, check that task manager is not showing anything else taking CPU/Mem/Disk.